TypeScript Error TS7017: Implicit any type for custom globalThis property in Pixi.js application
I'm working on a Pixi.js application where I need to store the application instance globally using globalThis. I've extended the Window interface to include a custom property PIXI_APP. However, when I try to assign the application instance to globalThis.PIXI_APP, I encounter the TypeScript error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.
I extended the Window interface in a declare global block and tried assigning the application instance to globalThis.PIXI_APP. Despite this, TypeScript does not recognize the property on globalThis, leading to the mentioned error.
declare global {
    interface Window {
        __PIXI_APP__: any;
    }
}

globalThis.__PIXI_APP__ = application;


Fixed this common issue while using PixiJS Devtools.
Tried like below and working fine at my end.


declare global {
    interface GlobalThis {
        __PIXI_APP__: any;
    }
}

export {};

(globalThis as any).__PIXI_APP__ = application;




Note - Declare statement will be use into global.d.ts and application statement will be your respective entry class where you have created the PIXI.Application instance.
